# Python Multiple Process sharing objects from one location?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pickle, shared

I'm currently re-writing a piece of software I wrote last year which was written using imperative programming and a database. I'm now looking at using object orientation and a better way of sharing variables via multiple processes.

Esstentially, the software connects to many units of hardware, listens for changes i.e. crosspoint changes on a router, and then saves this to a database/object. I then want a different process to be able to access that new change quickly and easily. This happens with multiple units of hardware all at the same time, hence the multiple processes.

This worked fairly well with an SQLite database, however I want to keep everything as an object to make use of attributes, neater code, spead etc.

Is there a way of sharing objects over multiple processes, being able to select and then 'put back' with relative ease? Also, the objects wouldn't neccessarily be in any particular order, meaning having to index to select an item would be off the cards.

I've previously looked at pickling object and saving them to SQLite, and queues. I'm pretty sure queues are the wrong choices, too limiting. I'm probably going to go with pickling + SQLite solution, just wanted to check with the web to see if anyone had any suggestions.

I hope I've explained myself well enough, thank you for your time!
Ned

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For sharing objects across multiple processes, you might want to look up "managed objects." The [documentation provided](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register) is very sketchy so you might want to do an Internet search on the subject looking for examples.